# Send activity to multiple notifications feeds

Tags: getstream-io

I need that an `user_1` can follow a topic to receive new activities from that. For example, from `tag:happy` feed.

When someone post an activity with `tag:happy` on a flat feed, everybody that want to receive `tag:happy` notifications, will be notified.

How is the best way to do that? It's just a `notification_feed` following a `flat_feed`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a follow between users' notification feeds and tag feed